# How to declare and use global variables?

Tags: spring-integration

i have a console application.i want to read some configuration settings from DB. And these settings should be stored in a global or session variable so 
i can use the variable through out the application , 
how can i implement it ? what are the ways ? which channels do i need to use ? and how payload should be stored?

Comment: please provide more information, such as which database you are using.

Comment: i can use any DB , my DB part is working well no issue . only concern how can i preserve rows in global variables , like we have session in web application .

Comment: on application startup, you can load data ( some table rows) and store them in static variable...which will be available throughout the application life-cycle

Comment: i know about static variable , but i am asking here in context of spring integration and  payload

Comment: Kindly refer this URL to achieve.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49494004/8392258

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not at all clear what you mean, but you can declare a Map object as a `@Bean` (or `<bean/>`) and load it up during initialization.

You can then reference it directly in your components by `@Autowired` or via SpEL in expressions in integration components: `@mapBean['foo']`.

Comment: thanks Russel , how can i sure that map will be filled in initialization phase ? because map should be filled before any object ?

Comment: You could use a [BeanPostProcessor](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/#beans-factory-extension-bpp) make sure it's `Ordered`, with an low order so it's invoked early in the context lifecycle. Be very careful which other beans you access there, though, you can cause issues by causing beans to be instantiated early.

Comment: if a add BeanPostProcessor , it gets executes after each and every bean , but my concern i want to execute a initialization block so that it can populate some values like static block.

Comment: You can ignore the additional calls, or use a `BeanFactoryPostProcessor` instead.