# how to resolve Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel?

Tags: spring-integration

my configuration is as below , i am getting no subscriber exception , how can i resolve ?

```
<bean id="Beani" class="org.util.Beani" init-method="init" />
<int:gateway id="configHelper" 
    service-interface="org.ncb.quickpay.grs.util.PartnerConfigReader"
    default-request-timeout="5000" default-reply-timeout="5000">
    <int:method name="getConfiguration" request-channel="configChannel" />
</int:gateway>

<int-jpa:retrieving-outbound-gateway 
    entity-manager="entityManager" request-channel="configChannel"
    jpa-query="select s from Setting s where  s.settingsCategory.category=:category">
    <int-jpa:parameter name="category" expression="payload['category']" />
</int-jpa:retrieving-outbound-gateway>
```

i am invoking this in a bean init method

```
public void init() throws Exception {
    System.out.println(" initialization global MAp  beni ");
    Map msgMap = new HashMap();
    msgMap.put("category", "web_service_dtl");
    Message msg = MessageBuilder.withPayload(msgMap).build();
    List<Setting> configList = configReader.getConfiguration(msg);

    if(configList!=null){
    for (Setting config : configList) {
        globalMap.put(config.getSettingsParameter().getParameterName() + "_"
                + config.getSettingsCategory().getPartnerId(), config.getParamValue());
    }
    }

    System.out.println(" map is  "+globalMap);

}
```

bean is defined in xml , and i am getting exception .

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'Beani' defined in class path resource [grs-spring-integration.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@23ab930d.configChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:776)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861)
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
at org.ncb.quickpay.grs.service.main.StartService.main(StartService.java:18)
Caused by: org.springframework.messaging.MessageDeliveryException: Dispatcher has no subscribers for channel 'org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext@23ab930d.configChannel'.; nested exception is org.springframework.integration.MessageDispatchingException: Dispatcher has no subscribers
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:81)
```

Please let me know how to resolve it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> i am invoking this in a bean init method

You must not start messaging in an `init` method; the application context is not fully built yet and the integration components you are using have not been started.

You can either implement `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` and put your code there; or implement `SmartLifecycle`, put you bean in a late `Phase` and put your code in `start()`. Either way, the integration components will have been started by that time.

It looks like you are still trying to solve [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40122805/how-to-declare-and-use-global-variables) to load global properties. I gave you another solution there which will work, but you can't invoke messaging components before the context is started; regardless of where you do it.

Comment: SmartLifecycle is the correct solution for my need, thanks Russell.

Comment: I had same problem and `ApplicationListener<ContextRefreshedEvent>` will not work, only `SmartLifecycle` is the option :)

Comment: Then you must have done something wrong; I can assure you it works - the event is emitted after all `SmartLifecycle`s have been started.